Overriding Scrollbar Behaviour
I am trying to override scrollbar behaviour . when I apply below code scrollbar is getting visible even if I am not scrolling . Meaning its always visible if there is scrollbar. before apply below css that was not the case .
I am expecting that scroll bar should be only visible when user is scrolling
  MuiCssBaseline: {
    styleOverrides: {
      body: {
        '-webkit-font-smoothing': 'subpixel-antialiased',
      },
      '*': {
        '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
          width: '6px', // Customize width
        },
        '&::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
          background: 'transparent', // Keep track transparent or default
        },
        '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
          background: '#BDBDBD', // Customize thumb color
          borderRadius: '80px', // Customize border radius
        },
        '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover': {
          background: '#A8A8A8', // Optional: Change thumb color on hover
        },
      },

